# Why might I be unable to delete entries and uninstall plug-ins in Craft CMS Solo 3.6.12?

Tags: delete

I know the two things may seem unrelated but the actions are both red items in their respective dropdown menus and perform destructive tasks.

In Entries, I was unable to delete a couple of test entries and some that had been deleted in a previous version of Craft (whatever version was out on 1/8/2021; on Craft Solo 3.6.12 now) were able to be restored and now they are sitting in my Entries list, unable to be deleted. The Entries are in a Structure section,m not a single as Craft won't let you delete those from the Entries page.

I went to check to see what plug-ins I have installed that might cause an issue but nothing jumped out at me. Since I had both CK Editor and Redactor (wanted to try each out) installed, I thought I might remove one and commit to the other for the remainder of this project. I was able to disable the plug-in but not uninstall it.

In either case, no errors appear, and clicking the action causes no visible hint that anything is occurring at all.

Comment: I think these are two unrelated problems. You can’t uninstall “Disabled” plugins, they must be enabled first to uninstall.

Comment: I realize you cannot uninstall disabled plug-ins, I was just saying that it's possible to disable them, just not uninstall them (after enabling them again, of course). I just find it curious that similar destructive actions are not working at all and I also realize that the two issues may still be unrelated.

Comment: To be honest, I’d recommend taking this issue(s) to the Discord channel. People may be able to help you work through these problems in real-time.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I always forget about Discord.

Comment: I did a little more poking around and discovered that this appears to be a browser-related issue in Safari. I've disabled the security features for this CMS domain and turned my AdGuard off as well but there's a browser-based modal that asks if you're sure you want to delete the entry or uninstall the plug-in. They won't appear in Safari but they do appear in Edge.